# Pattern Matching a Haskell list of variable size

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

**EDIT**: I shouldn't be coding when this tired. I was compiling a different copy of the program than I was running. Sorry for wasting your time.

I have the following code to make a single argument optional in my program's startup.

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    handleArgs args

handleArgs :: [String] -> IO ()
handleArgs (server:nick:channel:[]) = IRC.startIRC server 6667 nick channel
handleArgs (server:port:nick:channel:[]) = IRC.startIRC server (read port :: Int) nick    channel
handleArgs _ = putStrLn "Incorrect arguments given."
```

If I run it like `./program irc.freenode.net 6667 somenick #somechannel`, it runs. However, if I run it like `./program irc.freenode.net somenick #somechannel`, which should make args be a list `"irc.freenode.net":"somenick":"#somechannel":[]` if I understand it correctly, 
it gives a pattern match error pointing to the `args <- getArgs` line when I try to run it after compiling with ghc.

More precisely, the error is:
`mbot: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at core.hs:9:4-32)`

Comment: Just as a quick sidenote: That `main` function could better be written as `getArgs >>= handleArgs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your shell is not interpreting the part starting with `#` as a comment, e.g. bash with `interactive_comments` on (shopt). `#somechannel` may be interpreted as a comment.

Comment: That is the case for me and bash - he needs to escape the #.

Answer (score 2):

I think, your problem comes from the use of xs in both patterns,
when it would be fitting to match against []

```
foobar :: [String] -> String
foobar (a:b:[]) = b         -- matches on exactly two items
foobar (a:b:c:[]) = c -- matches on exactly three items
foobar _ = "hurz?"
```

This example works for me, and should hopefully do so for you, too .)

- Thing is, that matching against xs matches the empty list aswell as any other remaining tail.

Comment: No luck unfortunately, updated the code in the question though because  your way does make more sense.

Comment: No, his original version was fine - the problem is in something he hasn't shown.

Comment: I see.. than I can't reproduce the problem by now, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Could not reproduce:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    handleArgs args

handleArgs :: [String] -> IO ()
handleArgs (server:port:nick:channel:xs) = print 4
handleArgs (server:nick:channel:xs) = print 3
```

Output:

```
$ ghc --make match.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( match.hs, match.o )
Linking match ...
$ ./match
match: match.hs:(7,0)-(8,44): Non-exhaustive patterns in function handleArgs

$ ./match a b c
3
$ ./match a b c d
4
$ ghc -V
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
```

I think you're problem is elsewhere.  Perhaps you could make a minimal piece of code that actually complies and exhibits the problem?  That is usually an informative exercise.

Comment: Here is the full source to the file: http://github.com/Macha/Mbot/blob/master/core.hs . As far as I understand, the definition of IRC.startIRC should not affect this situation.