# Haskell Function with "split" cases

Tags: string, haskell, filter, split, case

How can I make a "split"ting case inside an function like this:

```
getBase64 :: String -> [Char]
getBase64 code
  | ("[&":c:r) = c
  | _          = ' '
```

This is so not working cause:

```
main.hs:7:11: Not in scope: ‘c’

main.hs:7:13: Not in scope: ‘r’

main.hs:7:18: Not in scope: ‘c’
```

The error is clear to me, but I'm a newcommer and don't know how I can do my "wish" ...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to match a pattern, but since you are using the `| cond = expr` notation, you are actually using a guard. Visit this page for more details about guards: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures#if_and_guards_revisited . `| ("[&":c:r)` actually means "a list constructed from the string `"[&"` and value `c` and value `r`", and Haskell compiler complains the variables `c` and `r` do not exist.

Here is how to define functions with multiple cases:

```
getBase64 ("[&":c:r) = c
getBase64 _ = ' '
```

However, this won't work because `"[&"` is a string, and Haskell thinks the first parameter is a list of strings. A string is a list of characters and you need to fix your pattern like this:

```
getBase64 ('[':'&':c:r) = c
getBase64 _ = ' '
```

Look at these examples for more details about pattern matching against characters in a string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602296/303939 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851126/303939

Then there is another problem: `getBase64` returns `[Char]`. If that's what you intended, your code should be fixed like this:

```
getBase64 ('[':'&':c:r) = [c]
getBase64 _ = " "     -- or [' ']
```

Comment: Ok. But I need more cases, like you see at: http://ix.io/mpl ... cause i want to get from "[&test]" the "test" out of it. My example isnt working .. why?